# HashMap or associative arrays in C

Tags: c, array, linked-list, hash-map

I am trying to implement an `HashMap` in C. I am trying to used a linked list style of interfacing to make adding and removing keys easy and efficient. Searching is not something I am considering at this point as it is early in progress. I am looking for any tweaks that could make this faster, more memory efficient, more practical, more dynamic, etc. as well as any serious issues you notice as I am merely an amateur at C programming and haven't much experience.

This is the header file with my declarations and implementation:

```
#ifndef _M_LINKED_MAP_H_
#define _M_LINKED_MAP_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* LinkedMap keys can be 512 characters long inc'l null */
#define M_MAX_KEY 512
#define M_KEY_NOT_FOUND 0
int _M_DEFAULT_VALUE_WARNED_ = 0; /* Issues one warning about zero default behavior */

/* TYPES */

typedef struct __LinkedMapNode {
    char *k; /* key */
    int v; /* value */
    struct __LinkedMapNode *next;

    /* determines whether key assign should happen to current node or node->next */
    int first; 
} __LinkedMapNode;

typedef __LinkedMapNode LinkedMapRoot;

/* FUNCTION DECLARATIONS */

int     LinkedMap_init (__LinkedMapNode *m);
int     setLinkedMapKey(__LinkedMapNode *root, char const *key, int value);
int     putLinkedMapKey(__LinkedMapNode *root, char const *key, int value);
int     getLinkedMapKey(__LinkedMapNode *root, char const *key);
void    delLinkedMapKey(__LinkedMapNode *root, char const *key);
void    LinkedMap_free(__LinkedMapNode *root);
__LinkedMapNode *LinkedMap_malloc();

/* FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATIONS */

int LinkedMap_init(__LinkedMapNode *m) {
    if (!_M_DEFAULT_VALUE_WARNED_) {
        puts("Please note: LinkedMaps return 0 on get if key is not found");
        _M_DEFAULT_VALUE_WARNED_ = 1;
    }
    m->next = NULL;
    m->first = 1; /* True if node is never assigned key */
    return 0;
}

__LinkedMapNode *LinkedMap_malloc() {
    __LinkedMapNode *m = malloc(sizeof(__LinkedMapNode));
    LinkedMap_init(m);
    return m;
}

int setLinkedMapKey(__LinkedMapNode *root, char const *key, int value) {
    /* this function is used to change the value of an existing key in the
     * linked list */
    if (root->next == NULL) {
        puts("You must put a key before you can set it.");
        return 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(root->k, key) != 0) {
        setLinkedMapKey(root->next, key, value); /* search until the key is found */
    } else {
        root->v = value; /* change value */
    }
    return 0;
}

int putLinkedMapKey(__LinkedMapNode *root, char const *key, int value) {
    /* this function is used only to assign new keys to nodes */
    if (root->first) {
        root->k = malloc(M_MAX_KEY);
        strcpy(root->k, key);
        root->v = value;
        root->first = 0; /* node has key, should not be reassigned */
    }
    if (root->next != NULL) {
        putLinkedMapKey(root->next, key, value); /* Recursive Call if possible */
        /* Picks up on all nodes after first assignment before penultimate node */
    }
    else{
        /* If the next node is null, recursion is impossible so 
         * direct assignment is used */
        /* takes on second assignment to root node and all subsequent assign calls */
        root->next = LinkedMap_malloc();
        root->next->k = malloc(M_MAX_KEY);
        strcpy(root->next->k, key);
        root->next->v = value;
    }
    return 0;
}

int getLinkedMapKey(__LinkedMapNode *root, char const *key) {
    if (strcmp(root->k, key) != 0 && root->next != NULL) {
        /* if the keys don't match and there are more check them */
        return getLinkedMapKey(root->next, key);
    }
    if (strcmp(root->k, key) == 0) {
        return root->v;
    }
    if (root->next == NULL) return M_KEY_NOT_FOUND; /* default value is zero if key is not found */
    return M_KEY_NOT_FOUND;
}

void delLinkedMapKey(__LinkedMapNode *root, char const *key) {
    /* Removing a key involves copying the entirety of the following node
     * to the node with the matching key */
    if (root == NULL) return; /* Silent discard if key not found */
    if (root->next == NULL) {
        if (root->k != NULL) free(root->k);
        root = NULL; /* last node is deleted */
        return;
    }
    if (strcmp(root->k, key) == 0) {
        if (root->k != NULL) free(root->k);
        root->k = root->next->k;
        root->v = root->next->v;
        root->next = root->next->next;
    } else {
        /* current root is not the correct key and so the next one is examined */
        delLinkedMapKey(root->next, key);
    }
}

void LinkedMap_free(__LinkedMapNode *root) {
    if (root == NULL) return;
    if (root->next == NULL) {
        if (root->k != NULL) free(root->k);
        free(root);
    }
    else {
        LinkedMap_free(root->next);
    }
}


#endif 
/* _M_LINKED_MAP_H_ */
```

Comment: P.S. The __LinkedMapNode is used because the entire Map is interfaceable from the root node so it should be used such that `LinkedMapRoot root = LinkedMap_malloc();` is the only node that the user will have to use as all actions can be performed on that

Comment: The`del` function is buggy - there's a path that deletes a node without checking the key. The `free` function looks buggy too. I think you need more tests and things like `valgrind` to verify your implementation. Biggest issue is that it's not a hash map at all - hint: you don't hash anything anywhere :-)

Comment: I actually meant LinkedMap not Hash sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use reserved identiferiers.

From 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers of the C99 standard

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.

This article is about C++; but it also contains a lot of information relavant to C. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065).

All the following are reserved for the implementation.

```
_M_LINKED_MAP_H_
_M_DEFAULT_VALUE_WARNED
__LinkedMapNode
```

Is there a use case were `LinkedMap_init()` would by used without a call to `LinkedMap_malloc`? If not just roll them into a single function. If so then keep them separate.

Why does `LinkedMap_init()` return an int but always return 0. If it can return an error condition then make it a void function. No point in wasting time returning a value if that value can never be used.

```
int LinkedMap_init(__LinkedMapNode *m) {
```

Malloc can fail. In your `LinkedMap_malloc()` you must either check for that before calling `LinkedMap_init()` or update `LinkedMap_init()` so that it can cope with a NULL pointer correctly.

```
__LinkedMapNode *LinkedMap_malloc() {
    __LinkedMapNode *m = malloc(sizeof(__LinkedMapNode));
    LinkedMap_init(m);
    return m;
}
```

There seems to be a bug in `setLinkedMapKey()`. If the key is at the end of the chain you fail to find it. Change `if (root->next == NULL) {` into `if (root == NULL) {`.

This is very dangerous.

```
        root->k = malloc(M_MAX_KEY);
        strcpy(root->k, key);
```

What happens if `key` is a very long string.

Comment: Question: suppose I check for NULL and it is NULL what would be the best course of action? `return`, `abort`, or `exit`?

Comment: Also, I originally had it `if (root == NULL)` but I would get a segfault if I tried the last node and when I changed it the last node updated properly, I also thought that was odd

Comment: @Tom, about your first question, for library code it is generally better to return some error indicator and let the caller handle the failure as appropriate. Application code can make more assumptions and it is sometimes fine to just `abort` on a failure case. But regardless of the choice, it is important to detect and handle errors always.

Comment: @Tom: Return NULL and let the caller check that the result is not NULL. Just because a container you are using does not work does not give that container authority to stop the program. The program may be able to take actions to get more space before retrying.

Answer (score 2):

@Loki's answer already pointed out very important things, here are a few others:

- Use booleans to communicate success or failure of a function if there are only two possible outcomes. All you have to do is `#include <stdbool.h>` and you'll have the `bool` type and `true/false` constants at your disposal.
- Use `enum` for compile-time constants. `#define`s have several weaknesses if compared, such as allowing silent redefinition and not producing a debug symbol (you'd see just a raw numeric constant in your debugger), among others.
- If you're logging error messages, use the [`stderr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stderr/) standard stream. That's the expected place to log runtime errors, so users of your code can filter normal `stdout` output from error messages.

  ```
  fprintf(stderr, "some error message here...");
  ```
- This seems like it should have been a comment documenting the behavior of the function instead:

  > ```
  > if (!_M_DEFAULT_VALUE_WARNED_) {
  >     puts("Please note: LinkedMaps return 0 on get if key is not found");
  >     _M_DEFAULT_VALUE_WARNED_ = 1;
  > }
  > ```
- I suggest using a consistent prefix for your function names. C doesn't have modules or namespaces, so it is a good idea to define some prefix that indicates the module a function belongs to. You could maybe prefix everything with `LinkedMap_`, example:

  ```
  LinkedMap_Init
  LinkedMap_GetKey
  LinkedMap_SetKey
  etc...
  ```
- You're blindly `strcpy`ing the keys without checking if then fit the `M_MAX_KEY` limit of 512 chars including null. Never assume calling code will be well behaved. Always check your assumptions, even if with just an [`assert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) to trap errors early and help you debugging.
- I also suggest validating input parameters against `NULL` if they are never meant to be null pointers.
- **Separate interface from implementation**, right now, including your file in more than one `.c` source file would result in duplicate symbols being defined. C requires you to define your functions just once in a `.c` file, while the header (`.h`) contains only forward declarations and data structures.

Comment: I don't understand how to separate the declarations because if I try to compile I get undefined symbols

Comment: Much obliged I particularly found useful the addition of name space like naming.

Comment: @Tom, you just move the function implementations to a separate `.c` file, then compile it with the rest of your program. That should be pretty much it. You are probably not compiling the source file with the definitions, make sure it is included in your workspace/makefile/whatever-build-system you are using.